# mysql UNION query not working

Tags: mysql

What am I doing wrong with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content 
WHERE threadName LIKE '%$filter%' 
ORDER BY lastUpdated desc 
UNION SELECT * 
FROM content 
WHERE threadName NOT LIKE '%$filter%' 
ORDER BY lastUpdated desc";
```

The first statement before the UNION works well on its own, but this one above returns:

> mysql_fetch_array() warning - supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Am I right in believing that UNION will not return duplicate entries, in which case the second SELECT statement doesn't need to have the NOT LIKE but will just return everything that wasn't listed in the first statement.

Comment: Does the second query also work on its own?

Comment: yes the second one works on its own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** This query should get you the rows matched by `filter` first, followed by those not matched:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN threadName LIKE '%$filter%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  lastUpdated DESC
```

Note that you should never `SELECT *`, list the necessary columns instead.

Comment: It sounds like he wants all matches to appear first, ordered by lastUpdate, then all non-matches.  

So the ORDER BY would have to be on a CASE statement against (threadname LIKE '%$filter%'), then lastUpdated.

Comment: I think you may have a point with the ORDER BY. What I'm really trying to do is to have all those results that were actually searched for ($filter) at the top and the rest beneath them so an ORDER BY at the end might change this surely?

Comment: And yes someone pointed out not to use SELECT * before, thanks, I will change that eventually

Comment: @LesterDove, kalpaitch: Thanks, my edited query should take care of that.

Comment: Cheers again. Aside from query speed what are the reasons for not using *. And what is the realy speed difference, have you seen any results?

Comment: @kalpaitch: Unless you only select columns that are part of an index, the speed difference will not really matter. By listing all columns you make reading the query easier (for humans) and it gets much easier to find out what columns are used by which queries. You are going to appreciate that once you try to modify/drop/rename a column :)

Answer (score 0):

While using UNION we must use column names instead of '*'.
Here, I m going to create .csv file at specific location on the system with emailid validation expression by using mysql query as bellow.
`select 'col1','col2','col3','col4' from tableName
UNION 
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM tableName WHERE col4 NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9.-]@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
INTO OUTFILE '/home/sachin/mysqloutput/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`